# Add class to the input of a td of the current tr within dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a dynamic knockout table that has a check box for "Qualification gained" when this is ticked i am looking to add a class to the inputs of `traininglevelselect` and `trainingDateSelect` (rows 0 and 4)

Table -

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: TrainingItems" id="trainingPadding" class="tdPadding">
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DropDownList("Train Level", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(TrainingLevel)), new { @class = "form-control site-level-ddl trainingLevelSelect", data_bind = "value: TrainLevel" })</td>
    <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainCourseTitle" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainProviderName" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="date: TrainDateStarted" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker2" /></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="date: TrainDateCompleted" class="form-control trainingDateSelect datepicker hasDatepicker"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" /></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainHoursAttended" class="form-control" onkeyup="calculateTrainingCost()" /></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" id="trainCost" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a cost" data-bind="value: TrainCost" class="form-control trainingCost" onkeyup="calculateTrainingCost(), calculateOverallTotal()" /></td>
    <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: QualificationGained" class="" onchange="addClass()"/></td>
    <td class="col-md-1" style="width: 4%; text-align: center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeTrainingRow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

To do this I am currently using jQuery to add the classes -

```
$('.trainingDateSelect').addClass('trainingDateCompleted');
$('.trainingLevelSelect').addClass('trainingLevel');
```

**The issue -**

This works fine if I only add one row. Dynamically adding a second row and clicking the checkbox adds classes to both rows.

I looking to just add classes to the current row the checkbox is on not all.

I have tried something along the lines of -

```
function addClass(){   
  $(this).closest('tr').children('input:eq(4)').addClass('trainingDateCompleted');
}
```

Which fires when the checkbox is clicked however it does not work.

Comment: Have you looked at the `css` binding? You should *not* use jQuery for DOM modifications and event handling outside of custom bindings when using knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch in the function name used in on change event in your code:

Pass *this* to the function so that you can refer that inside the function. You can use `find()` on the closest tr like the following way:

```js
function addClass(el){   
 $(el).closest('tr').find('input:eq(4)').addClass('trainingDateCompleted');
}

function calculateTrainingCost(){}
```

```css
.trainingDateCompleted{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: TrainingItems" id="trainingPadding" class="tdPadding">
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">test</td>
      <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainCourseTitle" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainProviderName" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="date: TrainDateStarted" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker2" /></td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="date: TrainDateCompleted" class="form-control trainingDateSelect datepicker hasDatepicker"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" /></td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainHoursAttended" class="form-control" onkeyup="calculateTrainingCost()" /></td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" id="trainCost" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a cost" data-bind="value: TrainCost" class="form-control trainingCost" onkeyup="calculateTrainingCost(), calculateOverallTotal()" /></td>
      <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: QualificationGained" class="" onchange="addClass(this)"/></td>
      <td class="col-md-1" style="width: 4%; text-align: center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeTrainingRow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great thanks you put me 90% of the way there i had to use - .find('td:eq(4) input') instead of .find('input:eq(4)') for this to update the input class on my code. Passing 'this' as the addClass parameter was what i was missing mainly though so thanks for that i will add as the correct answer.